# Table numbering incorrect

Tags: tables, numbering

Since trying to fix the problem described in this question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185905/tabularx-moving-table-to-next-page-ignoring-optional-arguments?noredirect=1#comment429924_185905

I have removed the offending Table and now noticed that my Tables have all been renumbered in the following convention: 1, 3, 5.

Trashing Aux Files does not fix the problem.

As per request, here is MWE which the table numbers as 1, 3, 5.
Removing the `\usepackage{ltablex}` cures the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{2.5ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\usepackage{ltablex}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\listoftables

\section{Section 1}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Heading 1} \label{tab:table}
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabularx}{0.90\textwidth}{ X X X }
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{3}{ c }{Multicolumn} \\
        \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Heading 2} \label{tab:table}
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabularx}{0.90\textwidth}{ X X X }
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{3}{ c }{Multicolumn} \\
        \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Heading 3} \label{tab:table}
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabularx}{0.90\textwidth}{ X X X }
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{3}{ c }{Multicolumn} \\
        \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved: As per one of the suggested answers to the other problem I had invoked the `ltablex` package in the Pre-Amble. Removing this has removed the problem.

Comment: That's very strange. Did you compile several times (do not forget that with this package, tabularx works like longtable).

Comment: At least 5. I wasn't actually using the package anyway, so it didn't matter then, but could help diagnose problems for others.

Comment: Could you send a minimal working example, in order to try to explain what's happening?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I was providing an answer to my own question as I had solved it.